# Hover over image

Tags: html, mouseover

I have seen on website like **pinterest.com** and few others that when you hover your mouse over image the facebook share or twiter share signs, number of comments and etc shows up. I have been searching on google  and I got answer of doing onmouseover Event, however i think they do something else. can anyone give me a hint or sample of a code. I want to be able when you hover over image you be able to share it with facebook, or twitter or email the image to someone. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a specific effect, it's best to inspect the code of the site and see how they do it.

Here is a very basic example that should help you get started:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
    <div class="info">
        Stuff here...
    </div>
</div>​

.wrap {
    width:350px;
    height:150px;
    position:relative;
}

.info {
    background:rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    opacity:0;
}

.wrap:hover .info {
    opacity:1;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uA2Lm/)

Comment: Hey, yes i have done inspect element, but it was very hard for me to figure it out, that is really great, what do you call this sort of things, is there like javascritp for this kind of things?

Comment: this doesn't works in ie8, just checked with hover image using above method